# Angular UI select : Fetch data from remote service

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-ui

I am using angular UI select.

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select

I looked around the demo's available at [this plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/juqoNOt1z1Gb349XabQ2?p=preview)

I want to fetch data from a remote service. Every time user types something into the text field. I want to fetch data from remote service with results filtered based on input value.

I have written a web service and web service is working fine.

How can I use angular ui select to fetch data from remote service ?

Currently I am following simple example from demo

```
  <ui-select multiple ng-model="multipleDemo.colors" theme="select2" ng-disabled="disabled" style="width: 300px;">
    <ui-select-match placeholder="Select colors...">{{$item}}</ui-select-match>
    <ui-select-choices repeat="color in availableColors | filter:$select.search">
      {{color}}
    </ui-select-choices>
  </ui-select>
```

`availableColors` is a predefined array. I don't want to define data array beforehand.

I have been looking around the Internet for any possible documentation or tutorial but not able to find anything useful.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

In your example, at first you must initialize your `availableColors` as an empty array:

```
$scope.availableColors = [];
```

Then, you can write your simple service with `$http`:

```
$http.get('data.json').then(
  function (response) {
    $scope.availableColors = response.data;
    $scope.multipleDemo.colors = ['Blue','Red'];
  },
  function (response) {
    console.log('ERROR!!!');
  }
);
```

So, now you can use this code without pre-defining your `availableColors` by some values.

#### Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/BcJOezOABxSuc2fa5lRy?p=preview

In this example I added file `data.json` which contains an array of colors.

It's a very simple example, but I hope that it will help you. Changes start from `line 118` in file `demo.js`.

### Edit

If you want to dynamically update your list of choices - you can use the attributes `refresh` and `refresh-delay` of the `ui-select-choices` directive.

The first attribute, as you can guess, gets function like

```
refresh="funcAsync($select.search)"
```

which will be called every time you type anything. And you can use the second attribute as

```
refresh-delay="0"
```

As you can guess it is used for set delay of calling `refresh` function in milliseconds. By default this value is set to `1000`.

#### Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/BcJOezOABxSuc2fa5lRy?p=preview

I updated my plunk, so I decided not to write own backend functions. That's why you can check it works by simply typing `red` in the first `ui-select` field - values will be got from another `.json` file - `data1.json`.

Hope, it will help you.

Comment: I want to call the service everytime user input some values in input box and the service will return the filtered result based on the value input in text box. This is necessary if I have more records as fetching all records at once is not good solution

Comment: @Syed: I updated my answer, so you can see that `ui-select` performs 2 attributes of `<ui-select-choices> </ui-select-choices>` directive: `refresh` and `refresh-delay`

Comment: In your function, you should return the `$http` promise so ui-select knows when it's resolved.

Answer (score -3):

Since you said:

> I want to call the service everytime user input some values in input box and the service will return the filtered result based on the value input in text box.

I believe you should `$watch` the input value for change, and query the remote source when the value is changed